# Proof of Cybenko's Lemma 1 in his "Approximation by Superpositions of a Sigmoidal Function" paper

Tags: measure-theory

The paper is [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~gvc/Cybenko_MCSS.pdf)

Here $\mu$ is a borel measure, $I_n$ the $n$-cube.

Cybenko defines $ \Pi_{y,\theta} = \{ x \mid y^\intercal x + \theta = 0 \} $ and $ H_{y,\theta} = \{ x \mid y^\intercal x + \theta > 0 \} $

Let:
\begin{equation}
    F(h) = \int_{I_n} h(y^\intercal x) \mathrm{d} \mu (x)
\end{equation}
Let $h$ the indicator function of $[\theta, \infty)$

So we have
\begin{equation}
    F(h) = \int_{I_n} h(y^\intercal x) \mathrm{d} \mu (x) = \mu (\Pi_{y,-\theta}) + \mu (H_{y,-\theta}) 
\end{equation}

According to Cybenko $F(h) = 0$ for that indicator function and I cannot see any reason why.

I must be missing something obvious and stupid but I can't see it

Thanks

EDIT: For example if we take $n = 1$ and $\theta = 0.5, y = 1$ with $\mu$ the lebesgue measure then it's false.

Does he *define* it to be $0$? Then why can he do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed like there was no reason for it to be true because it is indeed not true in general.

You have to use the equation proved before:

\begin{align*}
        0 &= \lim_{\lambda \to +\infty} \int_{I_M} \sigma_\lambda (x) \mathrm{d} \mu (x) \qquad \text{ because } \sigma \text{ discriminatory}\\
        &= \int_{I_M} \lim_{\lambda \to +\infty} \sigma_\lambda (x) \mathrm{d} \mu (x) \\
        &= \int_{I_M} \left( 1_{y^\intercal x + \theta > 0}(x) + \sigma (\varphi) \delta_{y^\intercal x + \theta = 0}(x) \right) \mathrm{d} \mu (x) \\
        &= \sigma(\varphi) \mu(\Pi_{y,\theta}) + \mu (H_{y,\theta}) , \forall \varphi, \theta, y
\end{align*}

This is true for all $\varphi$ and $\sigma$ is a sigmoid so we can take $\varphi \to +\infty$ i.e. $\sigma (\varphi) \to 1$. Which is true for all $y$ and $\theta$ and therefore in particular for $y, -\theta$.

We then obtain the equality in the original question.

Comment: The first equality's justification is not correct. You do not know that $\sigma$ is discriminatory - that is what you are trying to prove.